# what's the different between "cached image" and "local image"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I am beginner. I want to show images by urls on TableView, so I use AFNetworking+SDURLCache, just as below

```
// init URLCache
SDURLCache *URLCache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*2 diskCapacity:1024*1024*20 diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
[URLCache setIgnoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy:YES];
[SDURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

========================================================

```
// set cell    
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_URL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[[SDURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_URL]]];
```

Here, I use a image on all different cells. Everything works OK!  When I run my project first time, displaying images on cells need long time because my web image very large.   When I run my project second time, I found that TableView load images one by one immediately
? Why?why not load all images once immediately. I replaced the cached image to local image, TableView load images at a time. what's the different between "cached image" and "local" image?  SDURLCache did't work?

Comment: How big are your images? 50KB? 1MB?

Answer (score 0):

I have no iOS experience, but I would presume a cached image is an image that is stored in the web client's cache so that it will load that resource faster, unless that resource has been modified and the cached version invalidated since it was put in the cache.

A local image, I would assume, is an image stored on the device itself. Obviously this will be faster than downloading it as storage on the iDevices is comprised of NAND flash chips and such, which far outstrip a domestic Internet connection.